# Error on calling python script from php

Tags: php, python

Well, I have to call a python script from a php one but it does nothing. I've been searching but i couldn't fix it. The script creates 2 files and writes things in the terminal.

Here's my code:

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/script/myScript.py '.$path.' '.$specie.' '.$pvalue.');
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What if you run the script independently (not through php)?

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: You can look through the apache logs and figure out the error. Also most of the time, this is due to a permission issue. What are the permissions on your your script?

Comment: When you call a Python script from a PHP file, isn't the stdout re-routed to the PHP file and away from the terminal? So it makes sense that nothing would be printed. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, and `exec()` accepts second optional parameter for storing the output which is supposed to be in the terminal. so `exec('python myScript.py', $output)` will assign the output to `$output`, then it can be printed, but no matter the optional parameter is passed or not, the background execution such as creating files in the files system, will be done, so if there are no files created, then chances are - your php/web server user does not have permissions to write into the respective folder.

Comment: Sorry guys but I just finished my stay in that company and stop working on it. Also I forgot completely about this question. Thanks to you all of you anyways!